# GCM message expires despite arriving as expected

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

I'm sending messages over GCM with TTL=15 - and they arrive just fine. Despite that fact, the developer console (where GCM messages can be tracked) show status=expired.

According to Google's docs, expired means:
`Reached their time-to-live (TTL) and expired.`

Am I doing something wrong? Perhaps I'm not acking the message on my Android app?

Answer (score 0):

As [Reference](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref);

> time_to_live: This parameter specifies how long (in seconds) the message should be
>   kept in GCM storage if the device is offline. The maximum time to live
>   supported is 4 weeks, and the default value is 4 weeks. For more
>   information, see [Setting the lifespan of a message](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options#ttl).

So 15 seconds are too short to track you may want to increase this value.

Comment: thanks, but that doesn't quite answer my question. Clearly, the message arrives way before the 15 seconds are up, so why is it 'expired'?

Comment: Its expired since it already reached the TTL value ([source](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2663268?hl=en)) **Expired**: Reached their time-to-live (TTL) and expired

Comment: As @adjuremods said, GCM servers not hold all messages forever, deletes them when messages are reached to TTL value.